# What is the name of this type of bolt for the front crank on my bike?

Tags: maintenance, repair, gears, touring-bikes

I recently had to take the front gear off of my bike and had some difficulty undoing the bolts. Because of their poor condition, I have decided to replace them. However, I have no idea what they are called. I've included a couple photos that show the bolts themselves and the holes they are meant to fill. I had to saw the end of one of them off to get it out, and the Allen key holes are circular, so really they do need replacing.

[image: the bolts]

[image: the chainring, sans bolts]

Comment: Yep, chainring bolts.  Pretty standard item, though I suppose there may be 2-3 different sizes.

Comment: "size" in this case means length, even the imperialists use 10mm threads. So you get single ring, double ring, even triple ring lengths.

Answer (score 8):

They're called simply chainring bolts. The tool to hold the other part while tightening is chainring bolt wrench.

[image: Chainring bolt wrench]